# How can I convert this logic to Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn Java 8 Streams.
I want to convert this code to Java 8 Streams, but I also want to know what the Streams do.

```
List<Optional<Payment>> filteredPaymentList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Optional<Payment> payment : paymentList) {
        BigDecimal amount = availableToCreditFromNets(payment.get().getId());

        if (BigDecimalUtils.is(amount).isPositive()) {
                filteredPaymentList.add(payment);
        }
}
```

The `availableToCreditFromNets` returns:

```
public BigDecimal availableToCreditFromNets(Long paymentId) {
    List<NetsTransaction> netsTransactions = this.findAllNetsTransactionsByPaymentIdAndStatus(paymentId, NetsTransactionStatus.OK);
    BigDecimal amount = ZERO_WITH_TWO_DIGITS;
    for (NetsTransaction netsTransaction : netsTransactions) {
        amount = amount.add(netsTransaction.getAmount());

        //Find all credit transactions
        List<NetsTransaction> creditedNetsTransactions = this.findNetsTransactionsByOriginalTransaction(netsTransaction.getId(), NetsTransactionStatus.OK);

        for (NetsTransaction creditedNetsTransaction : creditedNetsTransactions) {
            amount = amount.subtract(creditedNetsTransaction.getAmount().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(-1))); //Amount from credit transaction is negative
        }
    }

    if (is(amount).isPositive()) {
        return amount;
    } else {
        return ZERO_WITH_TWO_DIGITS;
    }
}
```

`ZERO_WITH_TWO_DIGITS` have following logic:

```
public static final BigDecimal ZERO_WITH_TWO_DIGITS =
                    BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can use `paymentList.stream()
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .filter(amount->BigDecimalUtils.is(amount).isPositive())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` just I didn't get the porpuse of  usage `availableToCreditFromNets(payment.get().getId());` ?

Comment: `availableToCreditFromNets` , is a calculation where its return amount which is check for if the customer have any amount to get back. So i only want to get list `Payment` where amount is greater then 0. Did you dont see the code i posted? You see that i am using `availableToCreditFromNets` to check if there is any amount to give back.

Comment: Notice that such method is a bit redundant with the if-clause included in your excerpt. That's what Hadi was pointing.

Comment: sorry! it should be like this: `paymentList.stream() .filter(Optional::isPresent) .filter(payment->BigDecimalUtils.is(payment.getId()).isPositive()) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @HadiJ but in this streams, now i am now using the methid `availableCreditToNets` ? I need to check the amount with the method first.

Comment: @mac187 why do you need to check for `isPositive` twice? and why after all those checks for presence and mapping do you need to collect back as `List<Optional<Payment>>`?

Comment: I edited the post with `availableCreditToNets ` method. Thats why i need to check with the method first. My bad that i did not posted the whole method.

Comment: and what is the reason behind using `payment.get().getId()` without the check for presence of the `Optional`?

Comment: I am trying to figure out also how to check if Optional isPresent also so i can avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            List<Optional<Payment>> filteredPaymentList = paymentList.stream()
                    .filter(payment -> BigDecimalUtils.is(availableToCreditFromNets(payment.get().getId())).isPositive())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is what i tried to do.